# How can I find the biggest string of numbers?

Tags: c++, string, numbers

There are array elements e.g.: 2 3 4 7 8. I need to write to console what is the biggest string of numbers, so the solution will be 2-4, because 2 3 4 --> 4-2=2 is bigger than 7 8 -> 8-7=1

I need to find the longest growing row, which increases by 1. 2 3 4 (2+1=3, 3+1=4 and 4+1= 7 it's wrong. And in 2 3 4 row has 2 element and it's the longest not 7 8 where it is just 1

```
int first=0;
int last=0;

for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(t[i]-t[i-1]==1)
    {
        first=t[i];
    }
    else
    {
       last=t[i];
    }
}
```

With this code the solution is 7 8, so the code will the last pair (7 8).

Comment: Can you at least try to formulate the problem correctly? The "write to console" part is not the problem. Now, you are given an array of elements (are these ordered?) and you need to find "the bigest string of numbers"? The sequence which satisfies which property? Playing the guess game, I'd select 2-8, since 8-2=6 which is larger than the examples. And please, please: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I need to find the longest growing row, which increases by 1. 2 3 4 (2+1=3, 3+1=4 and 4+1= 7 it's wrong. And in 2 3 4 row has 2 element and it's the longest not 7 8 where it is just 1

Comment: Ok, now take the time to edit your question (text and title) so that the problem definition is clear to everyone, including yourself. Then keep editing until your example code (which is not the correct solution) can be copy and pasted into a file and compiled without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function takes an int array and size as input, as in your example code. And return the maximum increasing size. It may not be what you are looking for exactly, but your question is not very clear.

```
int func(int[] arr, int size) {
    // trivial case
    if (size == 0) 
        return 1;

    int max = 1; // At least 1 when there is an element
    int cur = 1; // At least 1 when there is an element
    int first;
    int second;
    int cur_first; 

    cur_first = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i+1] -1) {
            cur ++;
        }
        else {
            if (cur > max) {
                max = cur;
                first = cur_first;
                second = arr[i];
            }
            cur = 1;
            cur_first = arr[i+1];
        }
    }
    if (cur > max) {
        cur = max;
        first = cur_first;
        second = arr[size-1];
    }
    return max
}
```

Comment: the result is 7 8 for me :(

Comment: But i look your code again and it will be good, but i got wrong result

Comment: replace `cur = max` with `max = cur` in the middle